# Call Function in Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to call "decodeSimpleJSON" in SinpleDecoding Class, but the function is not available in the class.

```
class SimpleDecoding {

  *decodeSimpleJSON()*

  func decodeSimpleJSON(){
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    do {
        let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Launch.self, from: jsonData.data(using: .utf8)!)
        print(decodedData)
        } catch {
                print("Error Decoding")
        }
  }
}
```

Comment: Simply `decodeSimpleJSON()`. Could you explain more what is stoping you from doing this, it's hard to understand what the real problem is?

Comment: Where are you getting `jsonData` from?

Comment: "Call Function in Swift" i thought it was gonna be some weird marshalling problem !

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly place a function call in class, it has to be from the function

for e.g.

```
func callingFunction() {
decodeSimpleJSON()
}
```

Your final code should be look like

```
class SimpleDecoding {

  //calling function
  func callingFunction() {
    decodeSimpleJSON()
  }


   func decodeSimpleJSON() {
    let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .secondsSince1970
    do {
          let decodedData = try decoder.decode(Launch.self, from: 
          jsonData.data(using: .utf8)!)
          print(decodedData)
        } catch {
          print("Error Decoding")
        }
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put the function (*just* the function, not the class) into a Playground, then you can run it 'directly'. It will also give you insight on what does (or does not) work. In your example `jsonData` seems to come out of nowhere. You would have to provide it to the function as a parmeter. You would also have to provide  definition of the `Launch` class.